# Adding own graphics to the map?

Tags: qgis, graphics

Trying to add own graphics (.svg file containing lines as an extra layer) to the map in QGIS.

How to do it?

Comment: You have to make yourself some thoughts on the coordinate system and units of measurement of your "own" graphics. Otherwise your data might be placed in the middle of the atlantic at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island .

Comment: Thank you for a good adivce.

Answer (score 1):

Click the options in menu : Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Vector Layer.

Comment: Thank you. Having some problems with it cos it shows only basic lines on the map instead of a proper svg picture.